# why the + is required in regexp for ksh variable pattern manipulation

Tags: regex, ksh

Suppose if I wanted to extract the suffix string "**aabdcd**" from the string daaaaab**aabdcd** , the following expression is used in KSH,

> ${ex##**+**([!b])+([b])}

This means match and remove any character other than 'b' greedily followed by the character 'b'. What I don't understand is the + (highlighted in bold) preceding. Why is it required? Without it the regex fails to do the intended job.

```
#ex=daaaaabaabdcd
#echo ${ex##([!b])+([b])}
daaaaabaabdcd
#echo ${ex##+([!b])+([b])}
aabdcd
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The + represents the [regex quantifier](http://www.well.ox.ac.uk/~johnb/comp/unix/ksh.html#regexp) of the result. So with the + you may receive multiple results. Here are the other quantifiers that can be used:

```
?(pattern) matches zero or one times the pattern.
*(pattern) matches any time the pattern.
+(pattern) matches one or more time the pattern.
@(pattern) matches one time the pattern.
!(pattern) matches string without the pattern.
```

Comment: Thanks, that link made me realize the regex quantifiers are used at the left in Ksh. This had me confused as they are normally used at the right in languages like java.